# How to put the text front of a header?

Tags: html, css, text, header

Why I cannot put a text front of header.

I want to put them on a line without combining them (don't want put it in `<h3>`)

```html
<h3>Software</h3><a>version<a>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Headings are per default [block level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements). Simply set your heading to [`display: inline-block;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) to make them display inline but keeping block element properties:

```css
h3 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h3>Software</h3> <a href="#">version</a>
```

Comment: Hii Guys, You are missing </a> close tag

Comment: Thanks @HariomSingh for pointing out - totally oversaw that :)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use this code. Don't forgot to close anchor tag!

```css
h3 {
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>Software</h3>
  <a href="#">version</a>
</div>
```